# Trying to figure out a sql query to fetch the right data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I have a database and I have 4 tables (admin, appointment, doctor, patient).

I only care about appointment, doctor and patient.

Diagram of these 3 tables:

[image: Diagram of these 3 tables]

What I want is based on a patients amka(int) to find all his appointments and show his name, surname and doctors name, surname.

I made this query:

```sql
(SELECT doctor.name, doctor.surname
FROM public.doctor
INNER JOIN public.appointment ON doctor.username = 'alouisot2')
union
(SELECT patient.name, patient.surname
FROM public.patient
INNER JOIN public.appointment ON patient.amka = '713783001');
```

The problem with this query is that it will only show appointments between this specific doctor and I just want to get all the doctors names and surnames.

Also I use postgresql.

I was trying to figure it out but I couldn't. I need to restructure the query but I cannot think how I would solve this problem.

If you have any idea on how to do achieve this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables! Paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**!

Comment: Remove = 'alouisot2' and remove = '713783001'

Comment: @Grumpy If I remove them I will get an error cause after `ON` needs to be a **boolean**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - properly join the three tables together (doctor to appointment based on the common `username` column, appointment to patient on the common `amka` column), and define the `WHERE` clause with your desired values:

```
SELECT 
    doctor.name, doctor.surname,
    patient.name, patient.surname
FROM 
    public.doctor
INNER JOIN 
    public.appointment ON doctor.username = appointment.username
INNER JOIN 
    public.patient ON appointment.amka = patient.amka
WHERE
    doctor.username = 'alouisot2'
    AND patient.amka = '713783001';
```

Comment: Hey thanks!
I just removed the doctor.username = '...' part and it worked as I wanted.
As @NickW said I just made the problem more complex without a reason. I'm just a beginner in SQL so I still have some things mixed up, thats why I didn't structure it better.

Again thank you!
And everyone else of course!

Answer (score 0):

this query just needs simple joins; you seem to have overcomplicated it a lot for some reason...

```
SELECT 
patient.name, 
patient.surname,
doctor.name, 
doctor.surname
FROM public.patient
INNER JOIN public.appointment 
ON patient.amka = appointment.amka
INNER JOIN public.doctor 
ON appointment.username = doctor.username
WHERE patient.amka = '713783001'
```